# C# if hostname contains string then check array list

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am writing a program for work and when it initializes it goes through a series of if/else statements to check the computer name based on the building it is at, then when the statements find a match, it will print the building location onto a label in my form.

I am wanting to optimize this process by using an array list instead of 20+ if/else statements, and I am having an issue with it. Here is the code below:

```
string hostName = Environment.MachineName;
string[] buildingCode = {"B1","B2","B3","B4"};
string[] buildingName = {"Building 1", "Building 2", "Building 3", "Building 4"};

if (hostName.Contains(buildingCode))
{
     Console.Write(buildingName);
}
else
{
     Console.Write("Error!");
}
```

How I want it to work is that it will check the computer's `hostname` to see if it contains a string value from the `buildingCode` array. Then once it finds a match, it will use a string value from the `buildingName` array. But the Error List is displaying this error:

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'

I am still a slight noob at coding with C#, but I am learning a lot as I use this language and I try to avoid asking for help, but I am stumped. Any feedback/input would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: you are trying to print an array and also in if condition you are trying to validate an array, it should be a string, not an array

Comment: the error is occurring at: `if(hostName.Contains(buildingCode))` - with the red line under buildingCode string variable.

Comment: what is the value for hostname, show with your code in your question itself

Comment: What do you expect `hostName.Contains(buildingCode)` to check?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using wrong data structures that's causing confusion. Event if your building codes contain host name, how will you decide which building name corresponds to that code!

You can instead use `Dictionary` that stores building code/name as key/value.

```
string hostName = "B1";

var buildings = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "B1", "Building 1" },
    { "B2", "Building 2" },
    { "B3", "Building 3" },
    { "B4", "Building 4" }
};

if (buildings.ContainsKey(hostName)) {
    Console.Write(buildings[hostName]);
}
else {
    Console.Write("Error!");
}
```

P.S. While this solves your problem, I can't imagine how `MachineName` is going to match a building in reality!

**Update**: Since OP is learning C#, here's [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KWd95W) for him to play with.

Comment: Using a dictionary will keep your data in one place and create a relationship between buildingName and buildingCode. I prefer this solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cant compare string Array to String

> String[] = string Array

That's mean :

```
buildingCode[0] = B1;

buildingCode[1] = B2;

buildingCode[3] = B3;

buildingCode[4] = B4;
```

In your Code will be something like this :

```
        string hostName = Environment.MachineName;
            string[] buildingCode = {"B1","B2","B3","B4"};
            string[] buildingName = {"Building 1", "Building 2", "Building 3", "Building 4"};

            if (hostName.Contains(buildingCode[0]))
            {
                Console.Write(buildingName[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Error!");
            }
```

You Might need to put into the Loop to check all the array

Answer (score 0):

you cant write if(string contains array) You need a for-loop within a if.
like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= stringname.length; i++)
        {
            if (string.Contains(stringname[i]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(buildingName[i]);
                //Do something
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below. `Array.Exists` will check the `hostName` exist in `buildingCode` or not. `Array.IndexOf` will give you `index` of the match then you can get your `buildingName` based of the index.

Code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string hostName = "B1";
        string[] buildingCode = {"B1","B2","B3","B4"};
        string[] buildingName = {"Building 1", "Building 2", "Building 3", "Building 4"};

        if (Array.Exists(buildingCode, element => element == hostName))
        {
             Console.Write(buildingName[Array.IndexOf(buildingCode, hostName)]);
        }
        else
        {
             Console.Write("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Please check output in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MZBgYP).

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two different types, Contains method get a single string and not the array of string. Your code should look like as

```
 string hostName = Environment.MachineName;
        string[] buildingCode = { "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4" };
        string[] buildingName = { "Building 1", "Building 2", "Building 3", "Building 4" };
     if (buildingCode.Where(t => t.Contains(hostname)).Any())
     {
          Console.Write(buildingName[
          Array.IndexOf(buildingCode,buildingCode.Where(t => t.Contains(hostname))
         .FirstOrDefault())]);
     }
```

find here: [ActualCode](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OLhzO1)

Answer (score 0):

You can not check whole array with `Contains` function. if you wish to use `Contains` function you need to check each element of array

use `if (buildingCode.Any(x => x.Contains(hostName)))` instead of `if (hostName.Contains(buildingCode))`